# Diagrams with coloured boxes and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to do the following diagram but seems that I can't understand the TikZ package:

[image: Diagram]

How can i do it?

Im using the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}
      % for double arrows a la chef
      % adapt line thickness and line width, if needed
      \tikzstyle{vecArrow} = [thick, decoration={markings,mark=at position
      1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}}},
      double distance=1.4pt, shorten >= 5.5pt,
      preaction = {decorate},
      postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, white,shorten >= 4.5pt}]
     \tikzstyle{innerWhite} = [semithick, white,line width=1.4pt, shorten >= 4.5pt]


\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm] {
  \node (a) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Controlador de Solicitudes}; &
  \node (b) [draw, shape=rectanble] {Receptor Satelital}; &
  \node (c) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Decodificador}; \\
  \node (d) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Almacenamiento de Informacion}; \\
  \node (e) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Transmisor con GPRS}; \\
  \node (f) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Servidor Web}; \\
  \node (g) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Interfaz Web}; \\
  \node (h) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Autentificacion}; \\

};
\draw[->, thick] (a) -- (b);
\draw[->, thick] (b) -- (c);
\draw[->, thick] (c) -- (d);
\draw[->, thick] (d) -- (e);
\draw[->, thick] (e) -- (f);
\draw[->, thick] (f) -- (g);
\draw[->, thick] (g) -- (h);
\draw[->, thick] (h) -- (f);
\draw[->, thick] (a) -- (e);
\draw[->, thick] (e) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your attempt? And welcome to tex.SE

Comment: If you cannot understand TikZ, you might be able to understand PSTricks.

Comment: Edited with the code that im using! Thanks for the welcome. By the way seems that latex is not recognizing the draw command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the one hand, TikZ is *very* powerful and comprehensive, on the other hand, it is very hard to find solutions for concrete tasks. In addition, there are often many ways to realize graphics.

I tried to use you existing code and added the code you need to draw the given graphic.

Most things should be clear. Maybe I am wrong, but it seems that you don't have understood how to place content into the matrix. I hope this gets clearer now.

## Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{6095C9}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{55779A}

\matrix [column sep=10mm, row sep=8mm, every node/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    text width=2.75cm,
    minimum height=1.75cm,
    text centered,
    font=\sffamily\small,
    very thick,
    color=white,
    draw=blue2,
    fill=blue1,
}] {
  \node (a1) {Controlador de solicitudes}; &
  \node (a2) {Receptor Satelital}; &
  \node (a3) {Alimentatión Inteligente}; \\
  &
  \node (b2) {Decodificador desde NMAE a algo}; &
  \node (b3) {Interfaz Web}; \\
  &
  \node (c2) {Almacenamiento de Informacion}; &
  \node[xshift=15mm] (c3) {Autorizar y Autentificar}; \\
  &
  \node (d2) {Transmisor con GMS/GPRS}; &
  \node (d3) {Servidor Web}; \\
};

\begin{scope}[->, very thick, blue1]
  \draw (a1) -- (a2);
  \draw ([xshift=3mm]a1.south) |- ([yshift=3mm]d2.west);
  \draw (a2) -- (b2);
  \draw (b2) -- (c2);
  \draw (c2) -- (d2);
  \draw ([yshift=-3mm]d2.west) -| ([xshift=-3mm]a1.south);
  \draw[-, dashed] (d2) -- (d3);
  \draw ([xshift=5mm]b3.south) -- ([xshift=-10mm]c3.north);
  \draw ([xshift=-10mm]c3.south) -- ([xshift=5mm]d3.north);
  \draw ([xshift=-5mm]d3.north) -- ([xshift=-5mm]b3.south);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Graphic

[image: Diagram]

Comment: One little thing is that i don't know why after the \begin{scope}, the -> option is not working. If i delete that works perfect but I just can get all the lines (not the arrows).  Do you know what can it be ?

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean. Because of `\begin{scope}[->, very thick, blue1]` every line inside `scope` gets an arrow at its end. Why should you delete it? Or do you not want the arrows?

Comment: I want the arrows. The problem is that LaTeX tells me that there is an error if i don't delete it. Is there another way to do the arrows ? Thank you !

Comment: Could you post your complete current file? Maybe you do something before your picture which produces the error. I had no problems compiling my graphic.

Comment: Here's a [Screenshot](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/5581035?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1408145671&Signature=3HiDzawsM1HalPc7bZQnia5ruX8%3D). I didnt know where to copy the code. By the way i removed the colors in the meantime.

Comment: Sorry, I can't access the screenshot (Error Page with Access denied). But you should be able to edit your question and could then add a section (`# Update` or something like this) and add your current file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16484/discussion-between-dawu-and-tomas-campos).

Answer (score 6):

And just for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), using the `boxes` library, as described in [Drawing Boxes with Metapost](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf).  The main item of interest here is how to get the boxes drawn with white text on a blue background: you can't use the provided `drawboxed` command, because this does not let you specify a colour, so I've used the `bpath` and `pic` commands to get at the box outlines and contents, respectively.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
% load the boxes library 
input boxes;

% a little bit of plain TeX to wrap text in the boxes
verbatimtex
\def\wrap#1{\let\\\cr\font\sf=cmss10\vbox{\halign{\hfil\strut\sf ##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}}
etex

beginfig(1);
% define all the box names and text
boxit.con(btex \wrap{Controlador de\\solicitudes} etex);
boxit.rec(btex \wrap{Receptor\\Satellital} etex);
boxit.dec(btex \wrap{Decodifcar desde\\NMEA a algo} etex);
boxit.alm(btex \wrap{Almacenar\\Informaci\'on} etex);
boxit.trx(btex \wrap{Transmisor con\\GMS/GPRS} etex);
boxit.ali(btex \wrap{Alimentaci\'on\\Intellegente} etex);
boxit.inw(btex \wrap{Interfaz Web} etex);
boxit.aya(btex \wrap{Autorizar y\\Autentificar} etex);
boxit.svw(btex \wrap{Servidor Web} etex);

% position the centres relative to each other
con.c + 140 right = rec.c;
rec.c +  80 down  = dec.c;
dec.c +  80 down  = alm.c;
alm.c +  80 down  = trx.c;

con.c + 290 right = ali.c;
ali.c +  80 down  = inw.c;
inw.c +  80 down  = aya.w;
aya.w +  80 down  = svw.c;

% best guess at the required colors
color mid_blue, dark_blue;
mid_blue  = (79/255, 129/255, 189/255); 
dark_blue = (56/255,  93/255, 138/255);

% draw the boxes with blue background and white text
forsuffixes $=con,rec,dec,alm,trx,ali,inw,aya,svw:
  $.ne-$.sw = (89,55); % make them all the same size
  fill bpath $ withcolor mid_blue;
  draw pic   $ withcolor .95white;
  draw bpath $ withcolor dark_blue;
endfor

% draw the lines
drawoptions(withcolor mid_blue);
drawarrow con.e -- rec.w;
drawarrow rec.s -- dec.n;
drawarrow dec.s -- alm.n;
drawarrow alm.s -- trx.n;

z1 = (xpart con.c, ypart trx.c);
drawarrow con.s + 5 right -- z1 + (5,5) -- trx.w + 5 up;
drawarrow trx.w + 5 down  -- z1 - (5,5) -- con.s + 5 left;

draw trx.e -- svw.w dashed evenly;

drawarrow (svw.n -- inw.s)  shifted 10 left;
drawarrow (inw.s -- aya.nw) shifted 10 right;
drawarrow (aya.sw -- svw.n) shifted 10 right;

% draw a rounded frame 
drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled .8 withcolor dark_blue);
draw quartercircle scaled 1cm rotated   0 shifted urcorner currentpicture 
  -- quartercircle scaled 1cm rotated  90 shifted ulcorner currentpicture 
  -- quartercircle scaled 1cm rotated 180 shifted llcorner currentpicture 
  -- quartercircle scaled 1cm rotated 270 shifted lrcorner currentpicture 
  -- cycle ;

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Cool! Never heard about Metapost!